# has any easy way to get full url using python on gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

this is my code:

```
url = "/aa"
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
```

but it will be error , because you have to get the full url , like this :http://digu.com

so any easy way to get the full url in my code ,

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean the full URL of your own app?

You might want `self.request.host` (which would be eg digu.com) or `self.request.host_url` (which would be eg http://digu.com).

See the documentation for the [app engine Request class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html), and also the [WebOb Request class](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#method-url) it is based on.

However, why would you make a urlfetch to your own app?