# Get current URL in Python using os.environ

Tags: python, url

I don't *have* to use `os.environ` but that might be the easiest method.

I can successfully get the previous URL using:

```
sURL = os.getenv('HTTP_REFERER')
```

and the arguments of the current string using:

```
sURL = os.environ['QUERY_STRING']
```

but I cannot get the **current** URL.

[Other answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764586/get-current-url-in-python) advise:

```
sURL = self.request.url
```

(or [self.request.host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094715/has-any-easy-way-to-get-full-url-using-python-on-gae)) but when I do that I get:

```
 sURL = self.request.url NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

How can I easily get the current URL?

Full code:

```
import os

def GetTestMode ():

    sURL = self.request.url
    print '<br />sURL = ' + sURL + '<br />'
```

Comment: Please add some context. What is your class?

Comment: You need to tell us what web application framework you are using. Django? Turbogears?

Comment: @Tichodroma: created it outside a class (complete beginner). Is that necessary?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: no idea - how can I tell that?

Comment: How do you run your code? Do you type `python script.py` at the commandline, or browse to a website?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: browse to a website.

Comment: Down voter / close voter: please explain.

Comment: How did you set up that website?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: I'm reminded now that we might need to take this to chat, so I suggest we do if it goes on much longer. Thanks for your persistence. I have inherited this project so the website has already been set up (and I'm new to Python). If you ask me a specific question I will try to get the answer. As it is, I'm not sure what you are asking me.

Comment: Can you post the whole file of Python code that you are editing, or at the least, the import statements (lines such as `import numpy` and `from scipy import mat`)?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: apologies for delay, code added.

Comment: As it stands, your code cannot be helped. Please read a bit on Python and web development with Python first. Otherwise you’re just inviting a lot of pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague, this can be solved with:

```
    import os.path
    sURL = os.path.realpath('.')
    print 'sURL = ' + sURL + '<br />'
```

See [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) which says, *"Return the canonical path of the specified filename, eliminating any symbolic links encountered in the path (if they are supported by the operating system)."*

So this does not return the URL but the file path, but I can also use this.

Comment: This is not exactly what I asked for but, since it works for me, I'm posting it in the hope it may benefit others.

Comment: Note: I've posted an alternative solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22805154/283650).